# Error out of bounds exception when running recursive program in Java

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm learning about recursion as part of a Java tutorial and I am looking for a little   help.

We need to make a recursive Java program which will work out how to get from one city to the other when there is no direct flight.

My latest issue is Im getting an error out of bounds exception after the code has 2 cities in the flightRoute array List. it gives the error "IndexOutOfBoundsException Index 2 Size 2"

The connection value is an arrayList which takes all the cities that the city connects with and the flightRoute is also an arrayList which keeps track of the cities we have had to travel to in order to reach our destination.

I just cannot work out why it will not proceed.

I would appreciate some help on this if you could.

I do not want to overflow you guys with code so i'll put up the method that you should need. If you need more I will happily add some more code.

```
    public boolean determineRoute(City from, City to, ArrayList<City> flightRoute)
        {   

            //the Connections value takes all the connecting cities we can travel to from a departure point
            Connections = from.getConnections();
            City theCity = Connections.get(i);
            //searches in the connecting cities from the current city as to if it contains the city we wish to travel to
            if (flightRoute.contains(to)|| 7 >8) 
            {
            System.out.println("Congrats you can go their cause one of its connecting cities is the to city that u wanna go to");
            return true;
            }

            System.out.println("the City name "+theCity);
            if(flightRoute.contains(theCity))
            {
            System.out.println("Sorry it cannot be added "+Connections.get(i)); 
            }
            else
            {   
            //add connecting city to list for future reference
            flightRoute.add(Connections.get(i));

            //takes the lates connection and uses it for recursion (below)
            from = Connections.get(i);
            i++;
            //recursive part which sends a new from city for analysis until the city we want to travel to arises
            determineRoute(from, to, flightRoute);
            }   

        return true;    
        }
```

Comment: Your sample code uses `i`, but doesn't show where it's coming from... or why you expect to be able to increment it and ask for `Connections.get(i)` withotu problems...

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set the `i` value? Anyway, the only `get()` you do use `i` as index, so it is clear that `Connections` does not have as much items as `i`.

BTW:

a) Next time mark at which line the exception is thrown (from what I see, probaly the first `get()`

b) use lowercase for variable names: `connections` instead of `Connections`

Comment: i is initialised at the beginning of the file as in private int flightRouteSize, i =0; 
and The exception  is thrown on the line city theCity = Connections.get(i);
as well as on the recursive method itself below

Comment: since you're always incrementing i, and I bet on other parts of the code, it's more than normal that you'll end up having this error...
you need to instantiate the variable i within this code, so that whenever it's called it resets to 0, also, you oughta run this code within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `i` is *non* declared locally, so you're forever incrementing some instance variable. Declare it locally and set it to zero.

Before you can make any real progress fixing this code, I advise you clean it up:

- Name variables with a leading lowercase - ie `connections` not `Connections`
- Use local variables where it makes sense - like `connections`
- Remove nonsense code, such as the test if `7 > 8` is true - of course it's *always* true!
- Use proper indentation of blocks
- Iterate over collections using a "foreach" loop: `for (City city : from.getConnections())`
- Tend to name your variables the same as the class name, but with a lowercase letter, so `city`, not `theCity`

Comment: Thanks for your help I will fix my code and make it easier to read, its good you tell me this as I wish to code in the correct manner and I can only learn if others tell me where im going wrong.


With regards to the code would I be better off doing away with the i counter and finished? I have looked at this code for so long dont really know whats flying anymore with it.   :)